# SQL Server DELETE with OUTPUT not working with table alias

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I get an "Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'" error for the OUTPUT statement. Playing with it, it seems to be that the OUTPUT statement doesn't like the table alias D. But I need that for DELETE to work with the exists clause. Any idea how to fix this?

```
DELETE D FROM #VARNAMES D
OUTPUT DELETED.VARNAME INTO #Table2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CIT
                WHERE RID LIKE '123%'
                AND RULES LIKE '%Storage.' + D.VARNAME + '"%')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server the `OUTPUT` goes before the `FROM`:

```
DELETE D 
OUTPUT DELETED.VARNAME INTO #Table2
FROM #VARNAMES D
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CIT
                WHERE RID LIKE '123%'
                AND RULES LIKE '%Storage.' + D.VARNAME + '"%')
;
```

Comment: Putting the OUTPUT statement before the FROM statement worked. But curious, in this example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016 it is after the FROM clause. Is this because it isn't using the table alias after DELETE?
DELETE FROM dbo.table1  
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO @MyTableVar  
WHERE id = 4 OR id = 2;

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), the `output` goes before the `from`

```
DELETE D 
OUTPUT DELETED.VARNAME INTO #Table2
FROM #VARNAMES D
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CIT
                WHERE RID LIKE '123%'
                AND RULES LIKE '%Storage.' + D.VARNAME + '"%')
```